# My R code has a string of Japanese characters embedded in it. How can I run this R code on a R server?

Tags: r, server, character, setlocale

The code contains column names in japanese, which the server does not recognize.
Sys.setlocale(category ="LC_ALL","Japanese") does not work and throws error: cannot be honored.

library(dplyr)
a111<-select(Time,place,Department,営損営)

Answer (score 0):

You have not correctly specified the locale. Please try

```
Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_CTYPE", locale = "ja_JP.UTF-8")
```